# SQL запрос с выборкой из нескольких таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Зжравствуйте.
Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно сформировать следующий запрос:

- вставить поле `attribute_id` = `101` в таблице `oc_product_attribute` со значением `Черный` в поле `text`
  При таких условиях:
- поле `language_id` таблицы `oc_product_attribute` = `1`
- в таблице `oc_product_attribute` отсутствует поле `attribute_id` со значением `101` (нужно отобрать product_id, которым вообще не присвоено `attribute_id` = `101`)
- поле `name` таблицы `oc_product_description` содержит слово `%черн%` (может быть как вначале, так и в середине названия)

общий параметр в обеих таблицах: `product_id`

*Цель данного запроса: отобрать все товары, которым вообще не присвоен атрибут "Цвет", а в названии которых встречается слово "..черн.." - добавить всем таким товарам атрибут "Цвет" со значением "Черный"*

скрин таблицы `oc_product_attribute` http://prntscr.com/hi15l8
скрин таблицы `oc_product_description` http://prntscr.com/hi15vz

Comment: начнем с вашего sql-запроса, где он?

Answer (score 0):

Я не понял насчет `поле language_id таблицы oc_product_attribute = 1`. Без учета этого `language_id` запрос может выглядеть так:

```
INSERT INTO oc_product_attribute
(product_id, attribute_id, text)
(
SELECT a.product_id, 101, 'черный'
FROM oc_product_attribute a
JOIN oc_product_description d ON a.product_id = d.product_id
WHERE d.name LIKE '%черн%' 
AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT null FROM oc_product_attribute e WHERE e.attribute_id = 101 AND e.product_id = a.product_id)
GROUP BY a.product_id
)
```